# Python cursor is returning number of rows instead of rows

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sql-like

Writing a script to clean up some data. Super unoptimized but this cursor is
returning the number of results in the like query rather than the rows what am I doing wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import MySQLdb
import collections

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="admin", # your username
                      passwd="", # your password
                      db="test") # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the query you need
cur = db.cursor() 

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM vendor")

seen = []

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    for word in row[1].split(' '):
        seen.append(word)

_digits = re.compile('\d')
def contains_digits(d):
    return bool(_digits.search(d))


count_word = collections.Counter(seen)
found_multi = [i for i in count_word if count_word[i] > 1 and not contains_digits(i) and len(i) > 1]

unique_multiples = list(found_multi)

groups = dict()

for word in unique_multiples:
    like_str = '%' + word + '%'
    res = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM vendor where name like %s""", like_str)
```

Comment: You've got at least two `execute` statements here. Which one is doing the wrong thing?

Comment: the last one. the "like" statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the result of `cur.execute()`, which is the number of rows. You are never actually fetching any of the results.

Use `.fetchall()` to get all result rows or iterate over the cursor after executing:

```
for word in unique_multiples:
    like_str = '%' + word + '%'
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM vendor where name like %s""", like_str)
    for row in cur:
        print row
```

Comment: Do you need `fetchall()` in `MySQLdb`? With sqlite3, you can just do `for row in cur:`—and usually should. Besides being simpler, it's faster (besides the usual avoiding-an-unnecessary-list thing, looping over `fetchmany()` allows sqlite and/or the application to pick an ideal arraysize).

Comment: MySQLdb is somewhat archaic, and using the cursor as an iterator is only listed as optional in the [DB-API 2.0 spec](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249). Can't test it right now, but IIRC MySQLdb does not support it.

Comment: Correction: [`.__iter__()`](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L319) is supported but uses `.fetchone()` instead.

Comment: IIRC, MySQLdb's `fetchmany` is useless anyway; the underlying engine is already batching, so `fetchmany` just uses the same batch shared by `fetchone` (something like `batch[row:min(row+size, batchsize)]` instead of `batch[row]`). And it makes sense for `__iter__` to use `fetchone` if it's simpler and just as fast.

Comment: I see two cursor types; one that always fetches all results in one go and one that fetches rows one by one. I see no batched fetching, not in the `cursors.py` file I linked. Default is to fetch everything, meaning there is no difference between iterating and `.fetchall()`, really.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's why it's so much more important to use separate queries with `LIMIT` in MySQL than it was with Oracle/Sybase/db2; the only server-side cursor it has is `mysql_use_result`, which only sends back a row at a time, and keeps the query alive until you consume the cursor… OK, with MySQLdb, `__iter__` is probably no faster than `fetchrows`, and probably not much worse for memory (you do have to build the list, but you also let libmysql discard the client-side cursor immediately).